# How is a Msc thesis judged?

Tags: thesis

I will have to submit my master of science thesis (in the engineering field) in 2 months, therefore I would like to know which aspect of the thesis are taken into account the most in the final evaluation.

Also, is it mandatory for this kind of thesis to have as output a new procedure/methodology? And what if mine doesn't?

What are the main factors that the commission will focus on when deciding the final evaluation of the work done?

Comment: Ask your advisor. Only they can answer these questions for you in the context of your university's standards for master's theses.

Comment: Please ask one question per post: it makes your questions more clearly answerable.  Can you please split up this question accordingly?

Comment: @Bill Barth: the fact is that my supervisor doesn't even give me feedback when I send him the chapters I write, this is why I asked here

Comment: @jakebeal: actually the question is the one written in the title, the others are just to clarify my doubts about it

Comment: @Rhei OK; I have removed the final paragraph, which is really a separate question.  If you disagree, please edit the material to make it more connected to the main question.

Comment: Sending chapters may required too much of the advisor's time, and not make it obvious what you are askinig. Try asking a question instead.

Comment: **Every advisor/committee is different.**  If you want to know how your advisor will evaluate your thesis, you must ask your advisor directly how he will evaluate your thesis.  Not by sending chapters, not by asking for his opinion about your work, but by using the exact words "How will you evaluate my thesis?"

Answer (score 4):

Which aspects are taken into account with an evaluation depends highly on the university and master study. However, to give you some information about the process and evaluation, I can give you an example how this goes at the University of Amsterdam (The Netherlands), at the Faculty of Science:

The final evaluation is done by your supervisor and the second reader. And if you have a thesis defence, you will be evaluated by the supervisor, second reader, and one member of the board of examination. Then we have a list of aspects that will be taken into account. These can be found [here](http://student.uva.nl/binaries/content/assets/studentensites/fnwi/information-studies-masters/d.pdf?1369395824467) (PDF).

I hope this may help you to have more insight in the evaluation. Else, you can also look up some scientific articles for example at Google Scholar. And, depending on what kind of study you are doing, make sure your thesis is in the right format. For Computer Science for example, a thesis needs to be in [ACM Format](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigproc-sp.pdf).